# AvalonDock binding not working in DocumentHeaderTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalondock

I bind ViewModels (Items in xaml) to `AvalonDock`, everything works fine but in one case it fails.

`LayoutItemTemplate` works correctly and `DataContext` of `<v:CameraItemView />` (my UserControl) is set with ViewModel.

```
<ad:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" 
                   DocumentsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
                   ActiveContent="{Binding Path=CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <v:CameraItemView />                     
            </DataTemplate>                
        </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>               
        <ad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>                
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>  
</ad:DockingManager>
```

Problem is with `DocumentHeaderTemplate`, when I fill `Content` with static text it shows it correctly, when leave only `<Label Content="{Binding}" />` it shows  `Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutDocument`

`MainViewModel` of Window contains:

```
private ObservableCollection<CameraItemViewModel> items;
public ObservableCollection<CameraItemViewModel> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set
    {
        if (items != value)
        {
            items = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}

private CameraItemViewModel currentItem;
public CameraItemViewModel CurrentItem
{
    get { return currentItem; }
    set
    {
        if (currentItem != value)
        {
            currentItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
    }
}
```

Property in `CameraItemViewModel`

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        if (name != value)
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this property `Name` in UserControl `<v:CameraItemView />` it works.

Is there any possibility to access to item of collection ?

**My solution:**

Added `Content` on begin of path, because `ViewModel` is stored in `Content` of `LayoutDocument`.

```
<ad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label Content="{Binding Content.Name}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
</ad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Solved it by doing below,

### `DocumentHeaderTemplate`

```
  <xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.DocumentPath}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
  </xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
```

### `Resources`

```
<xcad:DockingManager.Resources>
   <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DocumentViewModel}">
      <Views:DocumentView DataContext="{Binding}" DocumentPath="{Binding DocumentPath}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</xcad:DockingManager.Resources>
```

### `LayoutDocumentPaneGroup`

```
  <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
      <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane/>
  </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
```

### `ViewModel`

```
public class DocumentViewModel 
{
    private string documentPath;
    public string DocumentPath
    {
        get { return documentPath; }
        set { SetProperty(ref documentPath, value); }
    }
}
```

Try adding `Content.Name` in the `binding` will solve your problem i believe. let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks, `<Label Content="{Binding Content.FullName}"  />` works. I forgot on `Content`.